# how to map bytecode line number to sourcecode line number

Tags: java, bytecode, javap

I'm creating a program to find null pointer dereference in java. The methodology used is to first extract java byte code using **javap** command and then extract control flow graph(CFG) information from it. Once CFG is obtained from byte code, i run an analysis on byte code to identify null assignment and dereference. If there is a flow possible from null assignment to dereference i point out those path.
Now the problem i have is i identify this null assignment and dereference in byte code as byte code line numbers. However showing byte code statements is no use. Hence i want to map the obtained line numbers to corresponding source code line numbers to show where it is assigned null. How do i make it happen?

**Note:** I know better than identifying in byte code its easy to identify in source code for null assignment however i started with byte code for the ease of extracting CFG and now i don't have time to change the program to analyse from source code.

Comment: You can get `LineNumberTable` to specify `-l` option of javap.

Comment: Parsing the output of `javap` sounds much more complicated than parsing the byte code. When using libraries like ASM, they will already do the mapping of line numbers to instructions for you…

Comment: yes i wanted a solution something like @Holger said. I tried searching for ASM but im not able to find a proper tutorial for it. It would be better if you can provide an example how to extract bytecode using asm.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) contains everything you need to know.